# EVO LABS 2.5 Portable Hard Drive

Tags: hard-drive

I need a USB cable for the above device so I can connect it to my pc and upload the pictures. does anyone know what USB cable I need? box states USB 2.0 which isn't much use to me.

Comment: Post a link to the drive you bought

Comment: Chances are it is this one....https://www.amazon.com/AmazonBasics-USB-2-0-Cable-Male/dp/B00NH11N5A

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the ports on the drive, look at the ports on your computer, search Amazon for USB 2.0 cables, and find the matching plugs, then you will visually see the one that you need.

A is usually the end that plugs into the computer, and B is usually the end that plugs into the smaller device.  USB C can be plugged either way.

For visual lookup : https://www.cablestogo.com/learning/connector-guides/usb